# No tests found for given includes (IntelliJ & Groovy)

Tags: java, testing, intellij-idea, groovy

I am attempting to run unit tests written in Groovy, using IntelliJ and ./gradlew command.
Building the project works fine, however the tests do not seem to be found. Running the tests in IntelliJ throws the following code:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> No tests found for given includes: [path.to.SomeTestClass](filter.includeTestsMatching)
```

No tests in my project are found, below is an example class I created in the project under 
`src -> main -> test -> groovy` directory.

```
import spock.lang.Specification

class SomeTestClass extends Specification {

    def "A test that should work"() {

        given:
        def someNumber = 1

        when:
        def anotherNumber = someNumber + 1

        then:
        anotherNumber == 2
    }
}
```

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Does "test" task run fine in console outside IDE?

Comment: @y.bedrov Thank you for your reply! I get a ```> There is no feature named IMPROVED_POM_SUPPORT``` when attempting to run in terminal

Comment: Is it possible to share sample project example for investigation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution:

This was solved by adding the following lines to build.gradle:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```